# Make programs in /opt searchable from launcher

Tags: path, executable

I've installed Telegram and I've the folder "tsetup.1.3.10", where executable files reside, into Download folder.

I don't want my programs in Download folder, so I moved they in `/opt` folder.
But, after that, I can't find Telegram from launcher search.

I added '/opt/' in $PATH defined in /etc/profile, but nothing!

Comment: So what is the full path of your binary, and what does `$PATH` currently contain? Note that subdirectories from `$PATH` will *not* be scanned for binaries.

Comment: My binary file's path: _/opt/Telegram/Telegram_

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt"(in /etc/profile)

Comment: What "launcher search"?

Comment: Maybe leave a symlink to executable in Downloads pointing to whats in /opt